# Error caused on runtime of java class file

Tags: java, javac, java-runtime-compiler

How do I compile and run java files if you don't know the specific package used by the developer...

I got a folder of java files written by someone else, and I'm trying to compile and run the java files, I can compile the files by running `javac *.java`, but if I try to run the main class by calling `java MainClass`, I get an error like so: `Error could not find or load main class MainClass, Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SomePackageName/MainClass (wrong name: MainClass)`

I have no idea whats the SomePackageName its defined by the developer and I have no control over that.

so the question is how do I compile and run the java files if all I know is which is the main class?

Answer (score 2):

1. Fully qualified class names are of the form: `com.foo.Bar`, where `com.foo` is the package (e.g. the file defining the Bar class starts with the line `package com.foo;`), and Bar is the name (e.g. the file contains the line `public class Bar {`).
2. When running `java` and specifying classpath+classname, you pass a class name. Not a file name. So to run this file you'd write `java -cp /path/to/base com.foo.Bar`.
3. fully qualified names must match directory structure both at runtime (class files) and compile time (java files). So, here you should have say `/Users/Foghunt/projects/myproj/src/com/foo/Bar.java` and after compilation you should have e.g. `/Users/Foghunt/projects/myproj/build/com/foo/Bar.class`
4. The 'base dir' is the one that contains the first package directory. So, the base dir for the source file is `/Users/Foghunt/projects/myproj/src` and for the compiled result is `/Users/Foghunt/projects/myproj/build`.
5. The base dir needs to be in the classpath. Classpath entries are file paths. So, to run this thing you'd write `java -cp /Users/Foghunt/projects/myproj/build com.foo.Bar`.
6. `javac` doesn't mind if you don't go through the trouble of properly defining things (e.g. running `javac *.java` in `/Users/Foghunt/projects/myproj/src/com/foo` does work), but it gets complicated quickly if you have multiple packages.
7. In general you should be using build systems. If you've inherited this project, check for a file named `build.xml` or `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` in the root of the project. If it is there, use a web search engine (`build.xml` -> search for `java ant`, `pom.xml` -> `java maven`, `build.gradle` -> `java gradle`), and use that to build the project, don't run `javac` yourself.

There you go. Armed with that knowledge you can now analyse, build, and run any java project.

Comment: The files that I receive are contained in single directory so each, for example canbeanythinghere/*.java files, basically as if the user just copied his classes on his IDE and just sent them in one zip folder, its not a full project so I don't have any build.xml or build.gradle etc', is it possible in to run many java files that use other java files in the same directory like this? I can run a single file easily with java single.java, but when it comes to many classes how do I compile and run them?

Comment: Yes. My explanations should make it quite obvious as to how to do this. basically, `cd ..; java -cp . SomePackageName.MainClass`